# How to pivot a ms access table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following **Data**

Table: persons

[image]

How can I reproduce the following **Results**

[image]

No there is no order and there is no ID. This was done by an average guy storing basic data, and I'm trying to produce these results to store it into the postgres server.

I saw the use of partition by but I am actually lost as to how to produce such results in such a fashion.

Here is a sample code for the sql query though there is not much to really go on

```
Select mother,father,child
from persons
order by mother, father
```

**This is using Ms Access 2010. Is this solvable or not?**

Comment: AFAIK, MS Access can't handle a dynamic number of result-set columns. SQL Server has PIVOT for this.

Comment: @jarlh since pivot wouldnt work, what would be the work around solution to build something of a similar result?

Comment: Why does postgres file store the data in non-normalized structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CROSSTAB query using DCount can accomplish if there is unique identifier field. Add an autonumber field to the table.

```
TRANSFORM First(Persons.Child) AS FirstOfChild
SELECT Persons.Mother, Persons.Father
FROM Persons
GROUP BY Persons.Mother, Persons.Father
PIVOT "Child" & DCount("*","Persons","Mother & Father='" & [Mother] & [Father] & "' AND ID<" & [ID])+1;
```

Alternative involves VBA procedure writing records to another table.