# In Access create a calculated column called order based on a column of dates

Tags: sql, ms-access, calculated-columns, crosstab, correlated-subquery

in Microsoft Access I need to bind a cross-tab query to a report.  To bind the query I need to know the column names in advance which is the problem as I do not know which dates will be in the data. The date names end up as the columns in the cross-tab query.  as the dates vary the column names vary and I can't bind the report as I don't know the column names.  the best solution I can think of is to calculate a column that replaces the date with its order.  then the column names will always be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.    However I haven't been able to create this calculated order column.  No matter what I do access bugs out.  Part of the cause is that This table will be used for a cross-tab query with parameters so access bugs out with any additional complications.

[image]

How do I turn StatusDate into CalculatedOrder?
Edit:
I cannot use a subquery to make CalculatedOrder as is sujested in the comments because the original query has parameters.  access bugs out when a subquery draws on a query based on parameters.

Comment: Review http://www.access.hookom.net/DynamicMthlyCrosstabRpt.htm and http://allenbrowne.com/ranking.html

Comment: The access.hookom.net link doesn't apply because the dates are random.  the allen browne link works but only for the very simple example I presented.  I need multiple columns included in the query which I thought wasn't relevant.   I may have to rewrite the question

Comment: Everything works fine with Allen Brownes solution until I try to use calculatedorder in a crosstab.  then Access throws an error.  it is clearly a bug.

Comment: And another approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56017569/how-to-pivot-a-ms-access-table/56020002#56020002. Provide representative examples of data as well as desired output.

Comment: it seems both approaches presented so far result in a calculatedorder that is an expression.  everything works fine until you try to use CalculatedOrder as the column variable in a crosstab.  Then you get the error: must enter group by in the total row for a field that has column heading in the crosstab row.  I may have asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem was two bugs in Access.  My guess is Access will bug at any additional complexity.  if the original table has parameters work with a copy of the table that doesn't have parameters.  In all cases, before calculating the crosstab, copy just your values into another temporary table.  In Access, crosstab doesn't work if a crosstab column variable is a correlated subquery. 
You can make the CalculatedOrder column using a correlated subquery similar to allenbrowne.com/ranking.html.
if the table has parameters:

```
PARAMETERS myfirstparameter
SELECT StatusDate, CrossTabRow, CrossTabValue INTO NoParametersTable
FROM MyTableWithParameters 
WHERE ...
```

Then make a query with only a grouped StatusDate.

```
    SELECT NoParametersTable.StatusDate
FROM NoParametersTable
GROUP BY NoParametersTable.StatusDate;
```

Then Turn StatusDate into Order using a correlatedsubquery:

```
SELECT CrossTabRow, CrossTabValue, (SELECT Count(dupe.StatusDate) +1 FROM [MyGroupedStatusDateQuery] as dupe WHERE dupe.StatusDate < [MyGroupedStatusDateQuery].StatusDate) AS [Order]
FROM NoParametersTable INNER JOIN [MyGroupedStatusDateQuery] ON NoParametersTable.StatusDate = MyGroupedStatusDateQuery.StatusDate)
```

finally make sure to turn this final query into a table without a correlatedsubquery by copying the values into another temporary table.  run the crosstab on the final temporary table and the crosstab will work because the final table just has values instead of parameters and a correlated subquery.